# Checking correctness of an instruction and addressing mode

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, error-correction

I'm given set of instructions and set of addressing modes that can used. In the first loaded byte is stored operation code of an instruction and in second byte is the addressing mode that instruction uses.

I'm supposed to check if there's an error and if there is, I should activate an insterror (instruction error) signal. Error is considered one of the following:

- Wrong operation code: Loaded code is not present in the list of available instructions
- Wrong addressing mode: Loaded addressing mode is not in the list of the available ones
- Wrong combination of OC and mode

So, I was thinking this way:

- Load first byte
- Check if OC is correct  -> if not then insterror
- Load second byte
- Check if mode is correct -> if not then insterror
- Check if OC **and** mode are correct -> if not then insterror

I'm not very familiar with eficient combining of logic components and I had a problem to find a way to, using one signal, test only for first byte, then only for second byte, then for their combination. So I've tried this way: since addressing mode is only given for address instructions, I've made this:
[image: Logic circuit 1]

So, basically, if it's one of expected instructions and expected modes, then I'll activate adr2 signal (which is short for address instruction of 2B). Similarily I did for the rest of instructions. Then I had this:
[image: Logic circuit 2]

Here, ST * immed is the only wrong combination of OC and mode here (STORE * immediate).

So here, I say, if none of the expected types of instructions are activated (bezadr1, branch2 etc.), then they'll all have value 0 which I'll invert to 1 with NOT gate, which will then activate AND gate which will activate insterror signal.

I'm currently having problems with rest of my problem, so I can't verify if this actually works, but I think the way of thinking here is okay. Now, even though this (may) work, I'm aware that this actually doesn't solve the problem in the way it's supposed to - since this only checks after 2nd byte of instruction is loaded and then basically checks possible combinations, so it's essentially doing only 3rd error check (but used in a way to check 1st and 2nd).

I think that ST*immed is how I'm supposed to check for 3rd error type. I'm thinking to use one OR gate fot "if one of error types then activate insterror", like in this pseudocode:
[image: Pseudocode]

But I don't know what and how to use to do 1st and 2nd error check the way it's supposed to be checked. Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:** I store operation code in first byte of register, then a couple of clocks later in second byte of register I store addressing mode. I'm given specific instructions and mode and how they are represented using bits of those two registers, so I know what is allowed to be written in registers.

It would be easy if I could use two signals to check for error, one for op code and one for modes, but I'm only allowed to use one. Now, if I could check for errors after second byte is stored, I think my solution from above would work.

But from how the problem is formulated, I think that it's expected from me to store first byte, then check if the op code is correct, then store second byte, then check for remaining two errors.

And I don't know how to do that using only one signal because of this:

I use inverted AND gate with available op codes - if none is activated (meaning it's not on the list of available ones) inverted AND will turn it to 1 and i'll have my error signal.
I use inverted AND gate with available modes - if none is activated inverted AND will turn it to 1 and i'll have my error signal.
But both of those gates are present in checking after storing first byte. First byte is storing op code, so I'll be checking for mode as well even though I didn't even store mode yet - which will result in error.
[image]

Comment: What does 'OC' mean?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Sorry, OC stands for Operation Code, I thought it would be implicitly clear since I mentioned it when I wrote what is considered error here, my bad.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I suspected, but the usual abbreviation of operation code is 'opcode'. In digital electronics 'OC' usually means 'Open Collector'.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yeah, my bad, I'll edit my post at the end, I think I wrote too much and didn't really made clear what's my main problem.

Comment: In broad terms what you’ll need to do, if I understand correctly, is to add an extra signal (or two perhaps) to indicate whether you’ve just fetched the first or second byte, and use this to enable the appropriate logic for each one.  You haven’t shown any kind of clock signal, which I find a little surprising - I’d expect to see a signal that would latch each byte into a register and then another signal shortly afterwards that would enable or latch the error indication once the logic had had an opportunity to settle.

Comment: @Frog Yes, that's how I'm going to do it in the end. I don't know how, but I was thinking that it could be done without it, but I don't think that's possible. Thanks.

Comment: I think it fair to say that you can only check the validity of the state of a register at a point where it *should* be valid.